# Как создать TXT файл в PHP с названием из формы?

Tags: php

Есть страничка HTML с простым тестом. На главной странице человек вводит в разные поля Фамилию, Имя, Отчество. После нажатия "Начать тест" его редиректит на страничку теста, а форма через .php файл записывает данные в текстовый файл. Не могу сделать, чтобы создавался файл с названием по Фамилии человека. Например, Иванов, создается файл Иванов.txt.

```
<?php
header('Location: test.html');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$work = $_POST['work'];
$today = date("d.m.y h:i:s");
$file = file_put_contents('$surname.txt', "\n $today $surname $name $middlename - $work \n");
fclose($file); 
?>
```

Comment: Для начала стоит понять разницу между строками в [одинарных и двойных кавычках](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но у меня код работает. Просто создается файл $surname.txt с записанными в него данными.

Comment: Ну так если код работает, то вопрос зачем тут появился?

Comment: Понял косяк, надо было $surname в двойные кавычки взять. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Подумай на досуге - куда запишутся данные, если `$surname` будет например `../../../../file.txt`.